# Simulating Failure to Access Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I create an Express.js library that uses the official Node.js driver for its Mongodb operations.

I'm currently in the process of writing unit tests and I want to simulate failures to access the database in order to ensure:

- The library acknowledges failure cases (handles the error)
- Makes the right error callbacks and fires the proper events.

I want the tests to run cross-platform, preferably without having to shut down or start the database with special parameters.

Looking at the [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) for commands, the [sleep](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/sleep/#dbcmd.sleep) command seems to do almost exactly what I want, but the waiting time in seconds in pretty long, plus it is flagged as for internal use only and you need to fire the database with a special parameter for it to work. The [forceerror](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/forceerror/#dbcmd.forceerror) command looks like another good one, but again, it's listed for internal use only and the description is vague to say the least.

I am wondering if there is any recommended (preferably not overly hackish) way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it requires superuser privileges for the node process executing this script to send signals to the MongoDB process without having spawned it, but it is the best I found so far to simulate unresponsiveness:

```
var MongoDB = require('mongodb');

MongoDB.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/SomeDB", {'server': {'socketOptions': {'connectTimeoutMS': 50, 'socketTimeoutMS': 50}}}, function(Err, DB) {
    if(Err)
    {
        console.log(Err);
    }
    else
    {
        DB.command({'serverStatus': 1}, function(Err, Result) {
            if(Err)
            {
                console.log(Err)
            }
            else
            {
                process.kill(Result.pid, 'SIGSTOP');
                //Put testing logic to test unresponsiveness
                process.kill(Result.pid, 'SIGCONT');
                DB.close();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Edit:

If your testing logic crashes on Linux, you can resume the MongoDB process manually on the shell by executing:

```
kill -CONT PID
```

Where PID is the process id of the MongoDB process.